# ManualResetEvent inconsistent behaviour with regards to unblocking

Tags: c#, multithreading

The current problem I'm facing is the fact that occasionally, a waiting thread does not proceed although the ManualResetEvent is Set.

So in ClassA I've got the following code snippet:

```
private ManualResetEvent readyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await RunAt(...);
        readyEvent.Reset();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var onRequiresRestartEvent = RequiresRestartEvent;

        if (onRequiresRestartEvent != null)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj=>onRequiresRestartEvent(this,
            EventArgs.Empty));
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> ListStuff(Match match)
{
    // Do some stuff
    readyEvent.Set();
}
```

In ClassB, I've got a method:

```
public override void WaitUntilReady(int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    if (!classA.ReadyEvent.WaitOne(timeoutMilliseconds)) // wait 
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Timeout waiting for the modem");
    }
    classA.ReadyEvent.Reset();
}
```

I've put a breakpoint on ClassA.ListStuff and readyEvent.Set() is indeed executed but for some reason, program execution doesn't get past the .WaitOne in ClassB.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this code? If not, what steps could I take to debug this issue?

Comment: How exactly ClassA and ClassB are instanciated? in the second part classA seems to be a field of ClassB. Are you sure that Set and WaitOne are executed on the same instance of ManualResetEvent?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why are you using `ManualResetEvent` with `await`/`async` code? In any case, why are you calling `readyEvent.Reset()` in your `Run` code? That removes the "ready" flag from the event, possibly causing your issues - if I'm not mistaken, if the Reset happens before the other thread has a chance to execute, it might not get signalled at all...

Comment: @Luaan. I am an absolute noobie at threading and the code I've got here is legacy code. So, your question was not stupid at all. I'll try and investigate your points and see what comes out of it.

Comment: @PashaPash ClassB is instantiated in a unit test while ClassA is instantiated within ClassB. With regards to your second question, how do I tell whether the Set and WaitOne are executed on the same instance of ManualResetEvent?

Comment: I vaguely remember having issues with ManualResetEvents when they were set by a different thread than the one that created them.

Comment: I'd recommend http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles to get you started. Multi-threading is easy to get wrong, and this (free) book is great at teaching you a lot of the concepts (and misconceptions) involved.

Comment: @Grzenio - never seen that.  Since the MRE is designed for inter-thread signaling, what you suggest seems err... 'unlikely'. There are issues with Events, (for instance, setting an MRE makes all waiting threads ready, but an immediate reset will change any remaining ready threads that have not beeen set running back to waiting again - crazy behaviour),  but what you describe is not one of them.

Comment: @DavidS, set breakpoint on WaitOne line. Check the value of classA.ReadyEvent using quick watch, right click on it, and pick "Make Object ID". That specific instance of MRE will be marked as #1. Then debug to Set line and check readyEvent value using quick watch. If the value is not marked as #1 than you are executing Set on some other instance of MRE.

Comment: @PashaPash: Thanks for the tip. In fact, that's the problem. In some cases, it's the same instance while in others it's not. So, thank you very much because now I have something to go on.